# useEffect is not triggered by a change in ref.current from a child component

Tags: reactjs

I have created a popup that the user can use to add stuff to the application, every field is a separate component, because I need to reuse them in several places in different configruations.

I have tried to create an `innerRef` that when changed (i.e. new value is typed), the `useEffect` of the component should be triggered to show or hide the `Done` button if all values are valid.

I know that all values are valid or not from the `valid` prop that I assign to `.current`

```
export default function AddStock() {
  const selectTypeOfQuantityRef = useRef({});
  const [allValid, setAllValid] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const allValues = [selectTypeOfQuantityRef.current.valid];

    allValues.every((value) => value) ? setAllValid(true) : setAllValid(false);
    console.log(allValues.every((value) => value)); // does not get triggered
  }, [selectTypeOfQuantityRef.current]);

return (
    <>
      <AddPopup>
        <SelectTypeOfQuantity innerRef={selectTypeOfQuantityRef} />
        {allValid && <DoneButton/>}
        <CancelButton/>
      </AddPopup>
    </>
  );
}
```

And this is the select itself (custom of course), that sets innerRef, whenever its state changes.
Everything here works, the state of this small component itself is managed correctly, but it just does not get triggered the state update of the parent component

```
export default function SelectTypeOfQuantity({ defaultValue = null, innerRef }) {
  const [selectTypeOfQuantity, setSelectTypeOfQuantity] = useState(defaultValue);
  const [valid, setValid] = useState(false);
  const [errMessage, setErrMessage] = useState("Избери стойност!");

  useEffect(() => {
    innerRef.current.value = selectTypeOfQuantity;
    handleValidation(selectTypeOfQuantity);
  }, [selectTypeOfQuantity]);

  const handleValidation = (value) => {
    const result = validateAutocomplete(value);
    if (result.valid) {
      setValid(true);
      setErrMessage(null);
      innerRef.current.valid = result.valid;
    } else {
      setValid(false);
      setErrMessage(result.errMessage);
    }
  };

  const selectTypeOfQuantityOnChange = (e, val) => {
    setSelectTypeOfQuantity(val ? val.value : null);
  };

  return (
    <Select onChange={selectTypeOfQuantityOnChange}/>
  );
}
```

Comment: Try changing the const to: `SelectTypeOfQuantityOnChange`. Its case sensitive issue i guess here in the first look

Comment: @MithunShreevatsa good eye Mithun, but thats not the issue, I have just mistyped it whhen transfering the code here. The onChange of select works just fine. My whole popup works just fine (if i remove the `allValid` condition), its just that I cant show back the `DoneButton`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`useRef` does not trigger rerenders, thus `useEffect` will not be called

Use `useRef` when you need information that is available regardless of component lifecycle and whose changes should NOT trigger rerenders. Use `useState` for information whose changes should trigger rerenders.

### Solution

As React's Philosophy states, all the data must reside within React, that's why even input components are supplied with a `value` and `onChange` event. React can't track data changes that happens outside it. As I understand from your question, the changes are happending within the React App, So instead of tracking the data  through the innerRef, track them within React using React's own methods.

Comment: useRef does not trigger rerenders, that is why I have placed it in the array of variables that useeffect should monitor.

Comment: Also refs cant be binded with components, you can include it with input elements or select elements, i see you have used for Custom component here. It should be vice versa. Custom component will not consist of attributes like current.value as its input attributes. It is better you trigger a function rather than binding it to ref i feel or as mentioned state change

Comment: I ended up making a new state variable in `AddStock` and a custom `onChange` function, I was trying to avoid that, because I thought that it will add too much additional code in `AddStock` (what I was trying to avoid in the first place, because I have many more fields), but it turned out much better than I expected.